# Custom DNS resolver is not working on Docker

Tags: docker, go, dns

I am working on a project and i created a custom dns resolver by using net package.

I have like 5000 DNS Servers. The program is working fine in my local machine but whenever I try to run it inside the docker container, it gives me an error like below:

> **lookup aaa.aaa.aaa on bbb.bbb.bbb:53: dial udp: lookup**
> **"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx": no such host**

- aaa.aaa.aaa: this is the domain name that I want to learn its IP
  address
- bbb.bbb.bbb: container's IP
- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx : This is the DNS
  Server IP.

Second problem is that if I use this resolver with `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1` its working both on my local host and inside container just fine.

This is my Resolver function. I am sure that the function is working just fine but i wanted to add it.

```golang
func Resolver(dnsClient, hostName string) ([]string, error) {

    r := &net.Resolver{
        PreferGo: false,
        Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
            d := net.Dialer{
                Timeout: time.Millisecond * time.Duration(10000),
            }

            return d.DialContext(ctx, network, dnsClient+":53")

        },
    }
    ip, err := r.LookupHost(context.Background(), hostName)

    return ip, err
}
```

I also try dig command on Ubuntu with some of the DNS Servers in my list but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you compile your binary, go might not be using your custom `Dail` function. If you look in [`net.Resolver.lookupHost`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/net/lookup_unix.go;l=79;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.5), it might use the CGO resolver in which case your Dail func is not used.

The resolver order is highly dependent on your environment. Setting `PreferGo` to true should make sure that the go resolver is always used and thus your Dail function.

You can set the `GODEBUG=netdns=1` environment variable, with this set the program should [log](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.5:src/net/conf.go;l=127;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17.5) which mode is used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I set PreferGo to true and compile it with "RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GODEBUG=netdns=1 GOARCH=amd64 go build -o prog . " It gives me the same error.